# How to echo all values from array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, dialog

I am making a bash script using dialog. My script make the difference between files in two tar.gz. Each add files are put in an array and each delete files are put in an other array.

All files are add in my two array and when I want echo them it's works

```
echo ${tabAjout[@]}
echo ${tabSuppr[@]}
```

The output is :

```
bonjour.txt.gpg test2.txt.gpg test.txt.gpg
hello.txt.gpg
```

Now I want add this in msgbox.

```
function affiche_message(){
    #Personnalisation de la fenêtre
    $DIALOG --title "$1" \
            --msgbox "$2" 20 45
}
```

Call function :

```
affiche_message "Title" "Delete : ${tabSuppr[@]} \n\n Add : ${tabAjout[@]}"
```

When I run my script the msgbox contains only the first values of the array. If I change ${tabAjout[@]} by ${#tabAjout[@]} the dialog windows echo that array contains 3 values.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use `*` as the subscript to expand the array as a single word:

```
"${tabSuppr[*]}"
```

See `man bash` for explanation.

Comment: Any way to get each item on its own line?

Comment: @zundi: The following seems to work: `( IFS=$'%'; ajout="${tabAjout[*]}"; suppr="${tabSuppr[*]}" ; affiche_message "Title" "Delete : ${suppr//%/\\n}\n\nAdd : ${ajout//%/\\n}" ; )`.

Comment: You got my upvote for the answer but "See man bash for explanation." not very usefull at all... can anyone explain this?

Comment: @eladsilver: When you use `*` as an array index in double quotes, bash expands the array as a single word, separating the elements by the first character of the special variable `$IFS`.